# Need list key and not list value from autocompleter struts2 tag

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, autocomplete, struts2

Struts2: I want to get List key in my action class from the autocompleter list and still want to display list value to the user.
For eg:

`<sx:autocompleter key="select Fruit"
list="FruitsList" listValue="Fruit.name" listKey="Fruit.key" id="Fruit"
resultsLimit="-1" searchType="substring" name="FruitName" />`

I have getter/setter for FruitName in my action class by which I am getting the listValue. I am able to get the list key by using javascript.

But is there a way to get listKey  without using Javascript and just by getter/setter or something else in my action class.

Comment: S2 dojo plugin is deprecated.

Comment: Off topic but you should name your java variables with lowercase according to camelCase convention.

Comment: Was writing an example so missed it. Sorry about that. It is deprecated but  the project I am working on uses it, so using it. Neways found the solution. We can use keyName attribute to get the listKey.